# Forgot Password link mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the mvc4 framework with openAuth feature active. Users can log in and register using an external login "Google" or Facebook.

My question is how do you implement a forgot my password system into this. All I have is their email address by default especially when they sign in as an external login. When they first log in with an external login it does ask to register the email into the system. Should at this point I ask for more information to validate the user?

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: If the users use external login, they have no password in your system, but rather in the external system... Right?

Comment: @khellang yes thats right, I have made a local account necessary on registration but offer the external logins as a service

Comment: But that "local account" don't have a password associated with it? I really don't understand why you would want to implement a "forgot facebook/google password" feature in your application. One of the main reasons for using external login is to not have different usernames/passwords everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no way you can implement a "Forgot Password" functionality within your application for external [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) providers.

Whenever a user logs in with an OAuth provider like Facebook or Google they will be redirected to their dedicated login pages. Whenever the credentials are not right, these pages will have their own "Password Recovery" functionality implemented.

The only thing you maybe could do is to offer a direct link to their recovery pages like http://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate. But as I said, that wouldn't provide a real benefit for your users because Facebook/Google's login pages will provide these links as well.